# Unity 2d - Inimigo seguir o jogador

Tags: c#, unity3d

Bom, estou com problema para fazer o inimigo seguir o jogador, fiz o código abaixo:

```
public class folow : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target;//set target from inspector instead of looking in Update
public float speed = 3f;
private Transform myTransform;


void Start()
{
    myTransform = this.GetComponent<Transform>();

}

void Update()
{

    //rotate to look at the player
    transform.LookAt(target.position);
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -90, 0), Space.Self);//correcting the original rotation



        myTransform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);



}
```

o problema é que ele apenas tenta ir em direção ao player, mas não consegue desviar de objetos e fica preso em qualquer obstaculo

Comment: Claro que não. Afinal, você *não incluiu nenhum código* pra ativamente evitar obstáculos, apenas moveu o inimigo em direção ao jogador ignorando o cenário. Se você quer que o inimigo ache um caminho até o jogador, precisará construir um [*pathfinding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding). Uma resposta que ensine a fazer isso seria muito ampla para o formato deste site. Você poderia construir um *pathfinding* próprio, mas eu sugiro usar o da Unity. Procure tutoriais sobre `NavMesh`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zzMTEKif4Q Depois, se tiver dúvidas específicas, volte aqui e pergunte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viva,

Basicamente o seu código está correcto... A agora falta-lhe dar inteligência para encontrar o caminho possivel para chegar ao alvo que marcou.
De forma simples tem:

- [A* Pathfinding Project](http://arongranberg.com/astar/)
- [NavMesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html)

Ambos são otimas escolhas... Apenas tem de ter em conta que em 2d apenas o A* Pathfinding Project é compatível.
Podia dar um exemplo, mas o código necessario é praticamente nulo, visto que já esta feito todos os scripts que necessita. (Em ambas as opções que mencionei acima)

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso que eu estava procurando, tentei usar o NavMesh nativo do unity mas ele só funciona em 3d